# How to stop anti alias mode to get a 1px line

Tags: .net, uwp, stroke

Basically, I want to draw some line of 1px stroke width.
But the lines were covering 2 pixels even after I set the value of stroke width to 1.
So I googled and learned about alias and anti-alias rendering.
Now, the solution I found an exact match problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879033/how-do-you-draw-a-line-on-a-canvas-in-wpf-that-is-1-pixel-thick) and the answer of this question comes with these two lines:

```
myLine.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
myLine.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

but these methods are most probably obsolete, because it shows error
that the Line class `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes` doesn't have these properties or method.
I also tried this:

```
myLine.UseLayoutRounding = false;
```

But that didn't work. Any help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to draw a line with X and Y coordinates, the coordinates define the center of the line.

So I assume you define the Line something like this:

```
myLine.StrokeThickness = 1;
myLine.Y1 = 10;
myLine.Y2 = 10;
myLine.X1 = 0;
myLine.X2 = 50;
```

This leads the center of the Line to be between two Pixels (Pixel 9 and 10 from top). So the rendering is always happening in the adjacent Pixels (and thus, at least in theory, leading to a blurry/wider line for every odd `StrokeThickness`).

To solve this issue try adding `StrokeThickness / 2` to your Y coordinates. So in this Example you'd solve it by setting the following values:

```
myLine.StrokeThickness = 1;
myLine.Y1 = 10.5;
myLine.Y2 = 10.5;
myLine.X1 = 0;
myLine.X2 = 50;
```

If you try to draw a vertical Line, instead apply to the X axis coordinates.